# About 'Remote Login' how to logout that?

Tags: macos, terminal, login

It's my first post and I'm not quite good in English. If I explained something not clear please let me know.

For simple when you logged in Terminal.app (on Mac OSX) the prompt should be

```
<hostname>:<path> <username>$
```

My local hostname is "Macintosh" but now my hostname is "foobar.com"(don't need to publish this name is for example)

I had enable the Remote function and logged in to the "foobar.com" as my self, confused? So I mean I do all of this on my local.

1. My local hostname was Macintosh, I enabled System `Preferences>Network>Remote Login`
2. I obtained foobar.com to log in.
3. Then, I logged @foobar.com.
4. My hostname is foobar.com and my group is staff.
5. I disabled Preferences>Network>Remote Login
6. Restart My Mac.
7. My hostname is still foobar.com and still  :staff.
8. So, I need to logout to be myself :admin and hostname "Macintosh"
   Because I can't do anything as admin, It's weird.

How can I done that?

for additional information If I turn-off Wi-Fi that I 
    ssh logged in to myself 
That is the result that I need.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all guys!

I just solved it by myself HeHe!
I think is simple error that I don't know Terminal.app too much.
The cause of problem is I command this

```
ssh <username>@<hostname_trough_remote_login>
```

and I didn't know how to logout, so It's just simple way to logout. use

```
exit
```

It's solved. (first I used `logout`)

Answer (score 0):

To change the Local Host name

Open Sharing

Click on Edit under Computer name

`Computers on your local network can access your computer at:` xxxyyy.Local

Change name to your liking.

Comment: I did but I think It doesn't work my local changed to "Macintosh" , but current logged user is staff that logged through remote, are you understand me what I say? XD

Answer (score 0):

Some networks give name for your computer upon connected and you'll see this name in terminal application.

When you disconnect this network and open terminal again you'll see your favorite name.